# "is the most logical order" vs. "is in the most logical order"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

My English teacher used this sentence in his question.

> Which of the following is the most logical order?

The question contained five answer choices (1,2,3,4,5), with each choices indicating a particular order of a,b,c,d (e.g. b-a-d-c). 
However, in my opinion, "Which of the following is **in** the most logical order?" is better English, since it is one of the choices (one through five), not the order itself, that is being asked in the question. 
From the perspective of a fluent native speaker, is there any grammatical, or contextual error in the first sentence?

Comment: The validity of the wording depends on how you understand the unspoken noun implicitly attached to "the following." If you read the question as asking "which of the following multiple-choice options is in the most logical order?" then "in the" seems preferable to simply "the." But if you read the question as asking "which of the following orders of the four sentences is the most logical order?" then "the" is preferable to "in the."

Comment: What Sven says. Or, to put it as clearly as possible: From a perspective of a fluent native speaker, there is no grammatical or contextual error in the first sentence. (Which coincidentally means that any answer containing the words "I agree with you" is wrong by definition.)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is nothing particularly logical about the order of the alphabet. It is arbitrary. Unless there is some further aspect of the question that you haven't told us, I agree with you.

I suggest:

"Which of the following lists is in alphabetical order?"

Ignoring my other objections, a more grammatical question would be:

*Which of the following [orderings] is the most logical ordering?*

Comment: Yes, actually I forgot to mention that letters a b c d respectively indicate paragraphs, and that the question asked the logical order among those paragraphs. Then is the use of the word 'order' impossible without the preceding of the preposition 'in' in this context?

Comment: Okay, I'll bite: How is the last question "more grammatical"? And what does "more grammatical" even mean? Something is either grammatical or it is not.

Answer (score 3):

> Which of the following is the most logical order?

Is grammatically ok. Actually using the "in" with the extra context you supplied would be slightly less sensible. Since you don't care about the ordering of the letters. Instead you care about the ordering of the paragraphs and the letters supply "an order" (actual a total linear order) on the paragraphs.